# translating a shape inside another one in opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I would like to be able to translate a smaller cube inside a larger by pressing some keys on the keyboard.

Below are my attempts to get this done:

initialy x = 0,y = 0,z = 0,origin = 0 and are global in scope

```
void key_board(unsigned char key, int xx, int yy){//call back func for the glutKeyboardFunc
      switch (key){
        case 'x':
          if(origin >= 0 && opposite >= 0 ){
            opposite = 1 - size -origin;
            x +=opposite; 
            break;
          }
        case 'y':
          if(origin >= 0 && opposite >= 0 ){
            opposite = 1 - size -origin;
            y +=opposite; 
            break;
          }
        case 'z':
          if(origin >= 0 && opposite >= 0 ){
            opposite = 1 - size -origin;
            z +=opposite; 
            break;
          }
      }
}

void solid_cube(double size){//this is the cube i would like to translate within the larger one,only perpendicular translation to the wall of bigger box are allowed

    glPushMatrix();
    glLineWidth(1.7f);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    glutSolidCube(size);

  }

void display(){//display call back func

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    gluPerspective(30.0, 4.0/3.0, 0.1f, 10.0);
    glFrustum(3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0);
    gluLookAt(2.0,0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glLineWidth(1.7f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glutWireCube(1.0); 
    solid_cube(0.3);//smaller cube to be moved around
    glutSwapBuffers();


}
```

Comment: Where are the values of `x`, `y` and `z` initialized and to what?

Comment: all `zero` and are global

Comment: if `size` happens to be `1`, `opposite = 1 - size -origin;` will evaluate to `0` and nothing happens

Comment: am taking it simple for now such that my size will always lie below `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code:

1. `glPushMatrix()` is called without a corresponding `glPopMatrix()`. As the names suggest, these calls manage a matrix stack. Every *push* operation must be matched by a *pop* operation, otherwise the stack will overflow quickly. To fix this, add the missing call at the end of the `solid_cube()` function:

   ```
   ...
   glutSolidCube(size);
   glPopMatrix();
   ```
2. Both `gluPerspective()` and `glFrustum()` are called. Both these calls serve the same purpose. `glFrustum()` supports setting up a general viewing frustum. `gluPerspective()` is a simplified convenience interface to `glFrustum()`, supporting only a symmetric viewing frustum. Both of these calls multiply the newly specified projection matrix with the current matrix. So if you have both, you will get a projection of a projection, which is... not something you want. You can simply remove the `glFrustum()` call in this code.
3. The projection matrix should normally be set up in `GL_PROJECTION` matrix mode. So the order of transformation setup calls should be:

   ```
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(30.0, 4.0/3.0, 0.1f, 10.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(2.0,0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   ```

   This is only needed once, so you can also move it to setup code instead of repeating it on every redisplay.

The parameters to `gluLookAt()` looks somewhat unusual as well. They're not illegal, but you may still want to double check the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to verify that it is really what you want.